# Change <select> options while the select box is in focus with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a login page where a html select element is updated every second to disable and/or rename the specific element.

Everything works but if you have e.g. an iPad you can focus the select element and then its not getting updated anymore until it loses the focus. And I have no idea on how to proceed from here.

that is the function which is called every second.

```
function editSelectMenu() {
    countedits = 2;
    const el = document.getElementById('stand');
    cams.forEach (element => {        
        if(cams[countedits - 2].shooter != ""){
            el.options[countedits].disabled = true;
            el.options[countedits].innerText = cams[countedits - 2].name + " " + cams[countedits - 2].shooter
        } else {
            el.options[countedits].disabled = false;
            el.options[countedits].innerText = cams[countedits - 2].name
        }
        countedits++;
    })
}
```

Comment: Does the problem only occur on iPad? Did you try your code on several browsers?

Comment: In Crome and Edge on Windows 10 and also in Firefox on Ubuntu and Chrome on Android it gets upated, on my iPad in Chrome and Safari not.

Comment: It's probably iOS UI taking the lead on the browser then. Did you check if only the visuals is not updated? Maybe the DOM elements get changed, but that change isn't send to the iOS UI.

Comment: Yes, its not updated at all.

Comment: Maybe you could force to lose focus using `blur` before making the changes?

Comment: I made a workaround for now and disable the submit button and display an error message if someone select the "wrong" option. 
If some knows how to solve it in any other way please let me know.